# Wicked JUnit Date trick - How would you do this in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Gojko Adzic posted today on his blog about Steve Freeman's unit-testing trick, which helped make it crystal clear why the date comparison in the unit test failed.  [Here is the blog post describing the trick - it is not long](http://gojko.net/2010/10/21/wicked-junit-date-trick/).

The key part of the trick is this method (in Java), which overrides **ToString()** on a particular instance of the **Date** class.

```
private Date namedDate(final String name, final Date date) {
    return new Date(date.getTime()){
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    };
}
```

It appears that this method uses a facility of Java language that doesn't have a match in C# (or at least one that I know of).  If you could show me how to do the same trick in C#, that would be awesome.

Comment: This isn't reflection, just an anonymous inner class.  I would imagine you could do the same in C# or just make a named subclass of C#'s equivalent date class.

Comment: @Mark: reflection was just a guess - removing the tag.

Comment: I can't think of a way to replicate it.  If DateTime wasn't a struct, we could inherit it and override, but it's not.  And extension methods won't override instance methods.  Thought about implicit type conversions, but they'd have to be defined on either string or DateTime.  Think you may be outta luck here, short of changing the test code.

Comment: @azheglov Looking at the root problem from the blog post, why not simply make use of the message parameter in the assertions? Say whatever you want to say in the message parameter...that's what it is there for...

Comment: If you _really, really_ want it in C#, I guess you could hack together something using _dynamic_. Not saying it will be pretty, though.

Comment: @qstarin: good comment, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @Aaron: the assertion message parameter is available in JUnit just like it is in NUnit and that doesn't solve the problem, which is why Steve Freeman had to resort to this trick in Java.  The best the assertion message can say that here are the two dates and they don't match.  That's the problem, not the solution.

Comment: @driis: yes, with dynamic or maybe with my own DateTime class wrapping System.DateTime.  Nat Pryce (co-author of GOOS) posted a comment on the same blog yesterday, saying that this trick cannot be done on final types in Java.  The same should apply to sealed classes and structs in .NET.

Comment: @azheglov The problem is readability, ignore the generated text from the assertion and placing something in the message such as "Process date (1) was earlier then Payment date (2)". How is that not the same thing? To be honest the mantra that it is somehow difficult/time consuming to "read" these tests when dates are being used is a bit over the top...IMHO

Comment: @Aaron: the problem in Adzic's example was not the algorithm under test calculated a date that was earlier or later than expected, but that the algorithm picked the wrong one out of three possibilities and that was communicated in a very unclear way. Freeman's trick was to "colour" those possibilities to make the wrong choice clear.  I think you're making a more general point than what this example is about. BTW, you could take it up with the experts! (Adzic, Freeman or Pryce).

Comment: @azheglov Clearly I am missing something, I don't see anything about color in that post...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is called an anonymous class in Java. It is really just a class implementation with no name, that overrides ToString()

You *would* be able to the same in C# with a normal, named class - the only problem being, that DateTime is a struct in C#, so you cannot inherit from it.

C# does have anonymous types, but not in the same way as Java. In C# you can have an anonymous type and specify it's properties, but you cannot specify any method implementations. Therefore, anonymous types in C# and Java tends to be used for different things.

## Edit

Here is an example on how you would do it in C#, but as stated above, you cannot do it on DateTime (or other `struct`s, or sealed classes) in C#. So for the sake of the example; I am using an imaginary class called Token, that has a single string property "Value":

```
private Token GetNamedToken(Token t, string name)
{
    return new NamedToken {Value = t.Value, Name = name};
}

private class NamedToken : Token
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Similarly, this trick wouldn't work for any primitive wrapper in Java (Integer, Double, etc) because they are marked final.

Comment: DateTime is not a class, it is a struct (value type).